# css nth-child four on four

Tags: css

I need to apply some style to every four elements in a list:

Right now I have:

```
.panel:nth-child(1) {background:#F0A46A;}
.panel:nth-child(2) {background:#EE8020;}
.panel:nth-child(3) {background:#BB6619;}
.panel:nth-child(4) {background:#887A4B;}
```

I want this behavior to repeat again in the 5th, 6, 7, 8 (and so forth) as the same as 1st, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7zA4T/)

```
ul li:nth-child(4n +1) {background:red;}
ul li:nth-child(4n +2) {background:blue;}
ul li:nth-child(4n +3) {background:green;}
ul li:nth-child(4n +4) {background:orange;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `n` in the selector. It will start at 0 and go through the list of child elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AeDxU/)

```
.panel div:nth-child(4n+1) {background:#F0A46A;}
.panel div:nth-child(4n+2) {background:#EE8020;}
.panel div:nth-child(4n+3) {background:#BB6619;}
.panel div:nth-child(4n+4) {background:#887A4B;}
```